# Touch support for arrow clicks on React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch-event, arrow-keys, touchstart

I am working on a React web app where I have a `div` of a `4x4` `grid` which has 16 `blocks` rendered in them. Where I have arrow click events for right, left, up, and down arrow. I need to add the mobile touch support for those arrow clicks when it's accessed only on mobile devices. I have never implemented these touch/swipe mobile features hence it seems very confusing. Any help would be appreciated.

**Component:**

```
const Grid = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState(new Grid());

  const arrowLeftKey = 37;
  const arrowDownKey = 40;

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (grid.hasWon()) {
      return;
    }

    if (event.keyCode >= arrowLeftKey && event.keyCode <= arrowDownKey) {
      let direction = event.keyCode - arrowLeftKey;
      let gridClone = Object.assign(
        Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(grid)),
        grid
      );
      let newGrid = gridClone.move(direction);
      setGrid(newGrid);
    }
  };

  useArrowKeyEvent('keydown',handleKeyDown); //hook

  const displayBlocks = grid.cells.map((row, rowIndex) => {
    return (
      <div key={rowIndex}>
        {row.map((col, colIndex) => {
          return <Block key={rowIndex + colIndex} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="grid" id="gridId">            
      {displayBlocks}
    </div>   
);
```

I came to know from googling that I would need to use `Touch Events`, such as `touchStart`, `touchMove`, `touchEnd`. Looking at the [touchevents documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)  I added the following piece of code to my component. I changed the `MouseEvents` to ´KeyBoardevent´. Since it's a `arrow key` `click`/`keydown` event. But this is not working. Not sure where am I doing wrong.

```
   const onTouch = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (evt.touches.length > 1 || (evt.type === "touchend" && evt.touches.length > 0))
      return;
  
    var newEvt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    var type = null;
    var touch = null;
  
    // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
    switch (evt.type) {
      case "touchstart":
        type = "keydown";
        touch = evt.changedTouches[0];
        break;
      case "touchmove":
        type = "keydown";
        touch = evt.changedTouches[0];
        break;
      case "touchend":
        type = "keydown";
        touch = evt.changedTouches[0];
        break;
    }
  
    newEvt.initEvent(type, true, true, evt.originalTarget.ownerDocument.defaultView, 0,
      touch.screenX, touch.screenY, touch.clientX, touch.clientY,
      evt.keyCode('37'), evt.keyCode('39'), evt.keyCode('38'), evt.keyCode('40'), 0, null);
    evt.originalTarget.dispatchEvent(newEvt);
  }
  
document.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouch, true);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouch, true);
document.addEventListener("touchend", onTouch, true);
```

I get the following error when I swipe right and expect for right arrow click:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

On the following line of code:

```
newEvt.initEvent(type, true, true, evt.originalTarget.ownerDocument.defaultView, 0,
      touch.screenX, touch.screenY, touch.clientX, touch.clientY,
      evt.keyCode('37'), evt.keyCode('39'), evt.keyCode('38'), evt.keyCode('40'), 0, null);
```

**Version 2**
**Edit:** : used `react-swipeable` after @sschwei1 suggested

I have added the following piece in the component :

```
  const swipeHandlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedLeft: useArrowKeyEvent('keydown',handleKeyDown),<<<<<problem 
    onSwipedRight: eventData => console.log("swiped right"),
    onSwipedUp: eventData => console.log("swiped up"),
    onSwipedDown: eventData => console.log("swiped down")
  });
```

and the return statement:

```
  <div className="grid" {...swipeHandlers}>
    {displayBlocks}   
  </div>
```

**Problem:** Can't use the hook as `callback` function.

Comment: As an aside, there's something wonky about `boardClone` and `gridClone` there...

Comment: @AKX corrected. They were mistakes.

Comment: There is a library which handles swipes for you, it's called [react-swipeable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable). There you can define handlers like `onSwipedLeft`, `onSwipedDown`, etc and just re-use your arrow logic

Comment: @sschwei1 Thanks for the suggestion. I used `react-swipeable` but can't use the `hook` I have for all those `keydown` events.  `  useArrowKeyEvent('keydown',handleKeyDown);` line of code is what triggering the hook. I can't use it in like this. `const swipeHandlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedLeft: useArrowKeyEvent('keydown',handleKeyDown)}
  });` . How can I reuse the `hook` here?

Comment: @shaz your `handleKeyDown` is the method which is called when a key is pressed, you could create a wrapper function for touch presses `const handleTouch = (key) => {handleKeyDown({keyCode:key})}` and in your handlers you write `const swipeHandlers = useSwipeable({ onSwipedLeft: () => handleTouch('37') });`, so basically you call your handleKeyDown function with an event only containing the keyCode you want to simulate, this is probably not the prettiest solution, but the first one I'd think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[React-swipeable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable) is a library which handles swipes for you, it enables you to create handlers for different swipe directions, e.g `onSwipedLeft` or `onSwipedUp` and pretty much all other cases you can think of like `onTap`, `onSwiping`, `onSwiped`, and many more.

In these handlers you can just re-use the logic of your arrow keys.

---

The first solution I would think of (not the prettiest solution, but easy to use and understand) to create a wrapper function for swipes and call the according keyHandler function to it

Here is an example of how these functions could look like:

```js
const handleTouch = (key) => {
  handleKeyDown({keyCode:key});
}
```

And in your touch handlers you can call this function with the according key

```js
const swipeHandlers = useSwipeable({
  onSwipedLeft: () => handleTouch('37'),
  onSwipedUp: () => handleTouch('38'),
  onSwipedRight: () => handleTouch('39'),
  onSwipedDown: () => handleTouch('40')
});
```

Since you are only using the `keyCode` in your `handleKeyDown` function, you can just pass an object with the `keyCode` property to the function and 'simulate' the key press